# Applications of Reactive Programming and Reactive Cocoa in iOS

Tags: reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I'm new to the Reactive Programming Paradigm. I had a glance over the documentation of the Reactive Cocoa in GitHub. I've found out few of the applications like replacing KVO, Asynchronous Programming in n/w, User Interface Interaction and Animations.

However, I was interested in knowing few examples of other fields can be candidates for the application of Reactive Programming(Reactive Cocoa in iOS, in particular)

Thank You

Comment: This is not the correct place for a question like this. You better off looking in the internet or asking in another StackExchange site.

Comment: What else would you need? As I see, Reactive Cocoa is a tool for making your code more modularized and pragmatic. You can win a lot if you can use it. Unfortunately, there is no definite answer for this question. Try RAC and if you have specific questions, ask again. Check out Ash Furrows book for some more in depth info https://leanpub.com/iosfrp